# Change cell values if a match is found

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet that has a textbox with a button that will be assigned to a macro. In this workbook there is another worksheet that holds the master data in a table. The textbox will have a job#. What I'm trying to do is lookup the job# in the job# column (column B/named range: "JobCol_Master") in the master table, and if a match is found, then in that row, verify a value based on what's in column D. If true, then change cell values in particular columns in that row.

I am getting a type mismatch error on line `Range(Cells(cell, 11)).Value = "Test"`. I am also getting an error when values don't match.

I appreciate any guidance anyone can give me.

```
Option Explicit

Sub IDCloseJob()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim MasterData As Range
Dim sourceID As Range
Dim cell As Range, row As Range, JobCol As Range
Dim Txt As String

Txt = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ID").TextBoxID.Text
Set MasterData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Jobs").Range("MasterData")


If Txt <> "" Then
    With MasterData
        For Each cell In .Range("JobCol_Master")
            'If job# matches textbox and if job# has value equal to "ID" in Column D then...
            If cell.Text = Txt Then
              Cells(cell.row, 11).Value = "Test"
            Else
              MsgBox "Job# not found."
            End If
        Next cell
    End With
 End If

End Sub
```

Updated Code:

```
Sub IDCloseJob()

Dim MasterData As Range
Dim sourceID As Range
Dim cell As Range, row As Range, JobCol As Range
Dim Txt As String

Txt = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ID").TextBoxID.Text
Set MasterData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Jobs").Range("MasterData")


If Txt <> "" Then
    With MasterData
        For Each cell In .Range("JobCol_Master")
            'If job# matches textbox and if job# has value equal to "ID" in Column D then...
            If cell.Text = Txt Then
              Cells(cell.row, 11).Value = "Test"
            Else
              MsgBox "Job not found."
              Exit Sub
            End If
        Next cell
    End With
 End If
End Sub
```

The above code if true doesn't complete the true statement `Cells(cell.row, 11).Value = "Test"`. It bring up the `MsgBox` then exits the sub. Not sure why...code looks right. If I leave out the false statement it completes my true statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
      Range(Cells(cell, 11)).Value = "Test"
```

To

```
      .Cells(cell.Row,11).Value = "Test"
```

Comment: One problem. It places the value "Test" in the row below the matched column. I can countered this by putting a -1 .Cells(cell.row - 1, 11).Value = "Test", but this negates the match rule and working within that matched row.

Comment: sorry but I don't get you: what do you mean by  _"row below the matched column"_? A row cannot be _below_ a column ... If you give more info I could try and help you. BTW, as long as your _original_ issue is concerned  (_"I am getting a type mismatch error on line Range(Cells(cell, 11)).Value = "Test""_) my answer solved it so please mark answer as accepted. thank you!

Comment: Sorry, it seems to be working, after I rewrote it in a new module. See updated code above. My false statement is causing me issues. I accepted your answer. Thank you.